# Can I merge this code about IFormCollection, IQueryCollection extension functions

Tags: c#, reflection

I wondering about this code.
How can I merge to one method?

Both methods give the same result.
But the parameters are different.
How can I merge in this case?

I tried to merge this code. but I failed. 
about `IFormCollection`, `IQueryCollection`

```cs
public static class extFunc
{
    public static string SerializeObject(this IFormCollection model)
    {
        if (model.Count == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var key in model.Keys)
            dic.Add(key, model[key]);

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);
    }

    public static string SerializeObject(this IQueryCollection model)
    {
        if (model.Count == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var key in model.Keys)
            dic.Add(key, model[key]);

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);
    }

}
```

I will expect like this code.
But this code was failed

```
public string SerializeObject<T>(T model) where T : ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>
{
    if (model.Count == 0)
        return string.Empty;

    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var key in model.Keys)
        dic.Add(key, model[key]);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);
}
```

Comment: they both implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,StringValues>>`, not `ICollection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost there. Both `IFormCollection` and `IQueryCollection` implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>`, so as in your sample:

```
public static string SerializeObject(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> model)
{
    if (!model.Any())
        return string.Empty;

    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var kv in model)
        dic.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);
}
```

Comment: thanks!! I knew `IFormCollection` and `IQueryCollection` implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>` but I didn't use that the `Count` property was missing . OMG.
I need strength to think at different angles.